# Get post excerpt and title by specific post ID?

Tags: posts, excerpt

I'm trying to get post excerpt and title by specific post ID.
My post ID is 6 and my code as follows

```
<?php
    $id = 6;
    $post = get_post( $id );
    $excerpt = get_excerpt( $id);
    $excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;
?>
<h6><?php the_title(); ?></h6>

<?php echo get_excerpt(190); ?>
```

It shows the title of post ID 6, but the wrong excerpt...
Also I've an excerpt length control code in my `functions.php`

```
// Changing excerpt length
function get_excerpt($count){
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $excerpt = get_the_content();
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $count);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = $excerpt.'... <a href="'.$permalink.'">Read More</a>';
    return $excerpt;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 4):

Your `get_excerpt()` function uses the `global` `$post` variable, which is out of scope inside your function.

```
// Changing excerpt length
function get_excerpt($count){
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $excerpt = get_the_content();
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $count);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = $excerpt.'... <a href="'.$permalink.'">Read More</a>';
    return $excerpt;
}
```

That means that when you do this:

```
$id = 6;
$post = get_post( $id );
$excerpt = get_excerpt( $id);
```

You are attempting to get the post ***content*** for the ***current*** post in the Loop truncated based on the ***ID*** of the post whose excerpt you are trying to get, but `$post` would be out of scope and thus "undefined". Then, assuming `$post` were set,...

```
$excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;
```

... you are then completely overwriting that generated "excerpt" data with the raw excerpt data from the current post in the Loop.

And then...

```
echo get_excerpt(190);
```

... you grab the excerpt ***from the current post in the Loop*** again, and echo it.

What you are doing is quite wrong in several different ways. I have to assume that you've copied and pasted that code without understanding it, which is quite dangerous. I'd caution you against it.

The WordPress Core function [`get_the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) will accept an ID argument, but [`get_the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) will not, so since you need both you are going to be best off simply retrieving the post object.

```
$id = 6;
$p = get_post($id);
// var_dump($p);
echo apply_filters('the_title',$p->post_title);
echo apply_filters('the_excerpt',$p->post_excerpt); // for a manually created excerpt
```

The generate an excerpt from post content, you'd need something like:

```
$text = $p->post_content;
$text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
$text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $text );
$text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
$excerpt_length = apply_filters( 'excerpt_length', 55 );
$excerpt_more = apply_filters( 'excerpt_more', ' ' . '[&hellip;]' );
$text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
echo $text;
```

Which is really just a simplified version of the Core function [`wp_trim_excerpt()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2355)

You can control the length of the excerpt using the [`excerpt_length`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length) filter. Per the example in the Codex:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Answer (score 1):

`<?php echo get_excerpt(190); ?>` this part is wrong. You are printing excerpt from `id = 190` just use `echo $excerpt`. Also you don't need the line `<?php echo get_excerpt(190); ?>`

Read the codex pages carefully you will see lots of helpful examples there to understand how a function works http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

Comment: not working...   <?php echo get_excerpt(190); ?> control the excerpt...

Comment: also i'hv a expert length in function.php

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a lot happening...

I'd try the following:

```
$id = 6;
$post = get_post( $id );
$excerpt = get_excerpt('190');
```

And use the following to display the excerpt:

```
echo $excerpt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you echo $excerpt variable?
I think this should work.
Don't do this:

```
<?php echo get_excerpt(190); ?>
```

do this:

```
<?php echo $excerpt; ?>
```

Comment: excerpt showing but no read more link...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the expert of a specific post with id 6, you can simply do as follow:

```
<?php
$id = 6;
$posts = get_posts($id)
foreach($posts as $post):?>
<h6><?php echo $post->post_title;?></h6>
<p><?php echo $post->post_excerpt();?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will simply give the title and the excerpt of the post with id 6.